# Creating two models in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

This is a sample of my code:

```
    <%= form_for [@facility, @owner],:html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages_doc' %>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td valign=top> First Name </td>
      <td ><%= f.text_field :first_name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign=top> Last Name </td>
      <td ><%= f.text_field :last_name %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <table width = "750">
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
    </tr>
    
    <%= f.fields_for :working_hours, @owner.working_hours do |wh| %>
    <div>
    <tr>
      <td><%= wh.object.week_day %></td>
      <td>
        <center><%= wh.text_field :start_time, :value => wh.object.start_time.strftime('%H:%M'), :style => "width: 100px;" %></center>
      </td>
      <td>
        <center><%= wh.text_field :end_time, :value => wh.object.end_time.strftime('%H:%M'), :style => "width: 100px;" %></center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </table>
    <tr>
    <td><%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
```

As you can see I am trying to create a owner with many working_hours (7 working_hours, one for each weekday). The problem is that this is working with edit, but the fields for working_hours does not show up when I try to create a new owner. I think the problem is that @owner.working_hours is looking for working_hours from the owner, which does not exist at the moment. Since I am creating a new owner, I need to create an array of 7 working_hours for the owner. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To create the `working_hours` use `build`. In your controller you might want something like:

```
class OwnersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @owner = Owner.new
    @owner.working_hours.build(Time::DAYS_INTO_WEEK.map{|name, value| { day_of_week: value }})
  end
end
```

Probably a bit overkill using `Time::DAYS_INTO_WEEK`, but I don't know what your attributes of `working_hours` are; just an example of how you can also set a default value for the created objects.

Just to explain, `build` can accept an array of hashes defining the attribute values of the newly created objects, so the above expands to:

```
@owner.working_hours.build([{:day_of_week=>0}, {:day_of_week=>1}, {:day_of_week=>2}, {:day_of_week=>3}, {:day_of_week=>4}, {:day_of_week=>5}, {:day_of_week=>6}])
```

So as you can see, it's creating seven objects with the `day_of_week` attribute set.

Comment: Thanks for a response. I added the line to the new method in my controller, but it doesn't seem to create the seven objects. I put <%= @owner.working_hours %> into my view, but all it displays is [], which is an empty array.

Comment: Unusual, it works perfectly well for me. Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :working_hours` in `owners.rb`? Also, `<%= f.fields_for :working_hours do |wh| %>` should suffice.

Comment: Yes I have that in my owners.rb